# Unable to read data from fixed size C array in Swift with out of bounds data

Tags: arrays, c, swift, firebird

I am working with a library written in C, Firebird, in my Swift project.
I have a fixed size C array, of size 1, in a struct

```c
typedef struct
{
    ...
    ISC_SHORT sqln /* number of fields allocated */
    ISC_SHORT sqld;     /* actual number of fields */
    XSQLVAR sqlvar[1];  /* first field address */
} XSQLDA;
```

Imported in Swift as a tuple

```swift
public struct XSQLDA {
    ...
    public var sqln: ISC_SHORT /* number of fields allocated */
    public var sqld: ISC_SHORT /* actual number of fields */
    public var sqlvar: (XSQLVAR) /* first field address */
}
```

The purpose of my code is to retrieve data describing a statement. For the statement `SELECT foo, bar FROM MY_TABLE;`, XSQLDA sqlvar array will contains two XSQLVAR, with description of the `foo` column and `bar` column.

In C, the struct needs an allocated size of `sizeof (XSQLDA) + (n - 1) * sizeof (XSQLVAR)`, as defined in the following macro in the library header

```c
#define XSQLDA_LENGTH(n)    (sizeof (XSQLDA) + (n - 1) * sizeof (XSQLVAR))
```

Creating a XSQLDA struct in Swift

```swift
let pointer = UnsafeMutableRawPointer.allocate(
            byteCount: MemoryLayout<XSQLDA>.stride + (Int(n) - 1) * MemoryLayout<XSQLVAR>.stride,
            alignment: MemoryLayout<XSQLVAR>.alignment)

var xsqldaPointer = pointer.bindMemory(to: XSQLDA.self, capacity: 1)
```

Passing this pointer to this struct to a C function of the library

```
isc_dsql_describe(&self.status, &self.statement, 1, xsqldaPointer);
```

This function will populate the sqlvar array of XSQLDA structure.

After this call, I iterate over the elements in the array

```
var sqlVariable: XSQLVAR = .init()
for i in 0...Int(xsqldaPointer.pointee.sqld) {
    withUnsafePointer(to: &xsqldaPointer.pointee.sqlvar) { ptr in
        sqlVariable = ptr.advanced(by: i).pointee
        print(String(cString: &sqlVariable.sqlname.0))
    }
}
```

Over the iterations, the address of the `ptr`, aka sqlvar th element, even advanced, stay the same. It seems that Swift can only access the first one.

Running the same function in C works properly. I looked in the memory with BitSlicer, and there are only one element when I run the Swift code, and `n` elements with the C code.

According to the documentation, the C code is

```c
for (i=0, var = out_sqlda->sqlvar; i < out_sqlda->sqld; i++, var++)
for (i = 1; i < my_struct_instance->count; i++) {
    var = my_struct_instance->arr[i];
}
```

I think the problem is coming from memory protection from Swift, but not sure. Any idea ?

I don't understand why to declare a fixed size array of size 1, which will contains an unknown number of elements. Why not a pointer ?

The function documentation is [there](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/InterBase/2020/en/Isc_dsql_describe()), and a code example of this function is [there](https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/firebird/blob/master/examples/api/api5.c). I'm aware that the documentation is about Interbase, by embarcadero. I looked the C code examples in the github, and the C API guide referenced by Firebird [there](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq233/)

Comment: What are `my_struct` and `my_function` in the documentation and in the code example?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Very thorough and well asked question, well done. What is the data structure declaration, in C?

Comment: Your code seems a bit too obfuscated. If you're calling Firebird functions, could you please use the actual types and names as defined in the Firebird headers. And a word of warning: you're linking to the InterBase documentation. Firebird was forked from InterBase 21 years ago, and they have been separate products since.

Comment: `Why not a pointer ?` - for example, because code should be documentation. The intention, the semantics - is to be array, so that is how it got declared.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I've updated my question according your comments.

Comment: What do you get if you add `print(i, ptr.advanced(by: i))` before `sqlVariable = ptr.advanced(by: i).pointee` ?

Comment: Basically it is a question of correctly marshalling from high-level language to low-level language, of cottectly defining low-level bytes-oriented structures in high-level languages trying to be bytes-agnostic. This is an interesting question about Swift - for Swifters. I suggest you to find communities that do exactly that, redefining well-known APIs in idiomatic Swift, and work it out with them. Alternatively, make a bridge DLL in C++, that would consume low-level FB API and expose some high-level API for Swift.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem did not come from the for loop, but from the memory allocation.

```swift
let pointer = UnsafeMutableRawPointer.allocate(
            byteCount: MemoryLayout<XSQLDA>.stride + (Int(n) - 1) * MemoryLayout<XSQLVAR>.stride,
            alignment: MemoryLayout<XSQLVAR>.alignment)

var xsqldaPointer = pointer.bindMemory(to: XSQLDA.self, capacity: 1)
```

The previous code allocate memory bounded to `XSQLDA` type, but the allocated memory will contain the `XSQLVAR` variables.

The proper way to allocate a `XSQLDA` is the following:

```swift
let pointer = UnsafeMutableRawPointer
    .allocate(byteCount: XSQLDA_LENGTH(numberOfFields), alignment: 1)
    .assumingMemoryBound(to: XSQLDA.self)
```

With the following function:

```swift
func XSQLDA_LENGTH(_ numberOfFields: Int16) -> Int {
    return MemoryLayout<XSQLDA>.size + Int(numberOfFields - 1) * MemoryLayout<XSQLVAR>.size
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have zero Swift knowledge (and my C knowledge is also limited), but the correct approach is likely to define `sqlvar` as an array, not as a scalar field. The `XSQLVAR sqlvar[1]` defines an array that defaults to a single value, but when `XSQLDA_LENGTH(n)` is called with n > 1, it actually defines an array of size `n`.

If possible, you should make it an array in your Swift tuple, and allocate *n* XSQLVARs in that array, and make sure that `sqln` is set to `n`. Then, after using `isc_dsql_prepare`, and `sqld` > `sqln`, you need to reallocate an `XSQLDA` with `n` equal to `sqld` and use `isc_dsql_describe` to populate it.

Alternatively, you can forego this and always use a `XSQLDA` of size 1 on prepare, and instead use `isc_dsql_sql_info` to 'manually' create appropriately sized `XSQLDA` descriptors for input and output fields.

This is the approach I take in Jaybird, the Java database driver for Jaybird. There, I either create an `XSQLDA` with size 1 (to use on prepare), or one with the right number of parameters/fields to manually create the descriptors based on the result of `isql_dsql_sql_info`, and allocate the necessary memory (that is because the way the Java implementation works actually shadows a native memory structure instead of directly accessing the native memory).

Comment: `sqlvar` is declared in the Firebird lib, I can't and I don't want to change the source code of it

Comment: @Gaune You also define it in your Swift tuple called `XSQLDA`

Comment: what I wanted to say is that the Firebird structs used in swift (like the previous XSQLDA) are not written by myself, but auto-generated for swift by clang using a modulemap. And clang convert c fixed size array into swift tuples

Comment: @ugocottin The alternative might be to try and bind to the OO API introduced in Firebird 3.0 instead of the legacy C API.

Comment: Swift cannot use C++ code, only C and Obj-C